# Extensions of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Fix an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ and let $X$ be the variety corresponding to the ideal $I_X$ of $k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ generated by $$A_X=\{f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\vert i=1,\ldots,k\}.$$ $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\leq k[x_1,\ldots, x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m]$, $A_X$ generates an ideal $I_{X'}$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n]$ and denote the corresponding variety by $X'$. Now define the variety $Y$ corresponding to the ideal $I_Y$ generated by $$A_Y=A_X\cup\{g_j(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m)\vert j=1,\ldots,l \text{ and } g_j\not\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\}.$$ $I_{X'}\leq I_Y$ and $Y\subset X'$.

> **Question: How should I refer to the relationship between $Y$ and $X$?**

In some sense, it seems reasonable to feel that I have constructed $Y$ as an extension of $X$. If I am not mistaken there should exist an infinite family of subvarieties $X^*\subset X'$ such that $X \cong X^*$ and that if $Y$ is non-empty there exists a subfamily $X^{**}$ such that $X^{**}\cap Y$ is non-empty and $(\bigcup X^{**})\cap Y=Y$. Additionally, the coordinate ring $A(X)$ should be a subring of $A(Y)$ and so $A(Y)$ can be viewed as an extension of $A(X)$.

I would imagine that someone has studied this sort of thing before, but in my ignorance I do not know where to look or what to search for. I have been trying to consult Hartshorne to get a handle on this, and I very much like it, but the book seems rather mum on the subject.

Comment: As long as we're being careful: I would not say that $I_X$ is an ideal in $k[x,y]$

Comment: To take a step back: geometrically, what are you trying to accomplish with this construction?

Comment: What I'm interested in studying are fusion categories and structures (braided, pivotal) which may be added to them. Given some input data I can obtain a fusion category by solving a system of polynomial equations known as pentagon equations. Given a fusion category and solution to the pentagons, pivotal/braided structures correspond to solutions of additional polynomial equations involving variables from the pentagons and new ones. Details can be found in [1305.2229](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2229) but the construction is generalized by the procedure described in the question.

Comment: Oh, gosh, I was asking on a simpler level -- just in terms of classical algebraic geometry. Oddly enough I know Orit...